# Calling helper method in services

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

Can't seem to call this helper method from a service I created. They look like this:

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :activate_session_with_id

 def activate_session_with_id(domain, token)
   #do some stuff
 end
end
```

My service looks like:

```
# app/services/fulfillment_order.rb
class FulfillmentOrder
  def create_order_user_fulfilled
    shop = Shop.find_by(shopify_domain: @domain)
    shop_token = shop.shopify_token
    ApplicationController.helpers.activate_shopify_session_with_id(@domain, shop_token)
  end
end
```

When I do that, I get this error

```
NoMethodError  (undefined method activate_shopify_session_with_id
```

I also tried to call the helper method straight up, like this:

```
activate_shopify_session_with_id(@domain, shop_token)
```

No luck with either way. Where did I go astray?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need of calling controller's method **outside** of controller means you have defined this method in the *wrong place*.

You could move the method to some helper module and use in both places (by including it).

That's said, to make your attempt working:

```
ApplicationController.new.activate_session_with_id(domain, token)
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestion.Ahh, so if I created a module for this method, I would just include the module in the service and call the method as needed? Yes?

Comment: @ToddT yea, you would include it in any class, that uses this method :)